# How do you throw an exception from a custom workflow activity in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

How do you throw an exception from a custom workflow activity in CRM 2011 so that the user sees it? From a plugin I can throw InvalidPluginExecutionException, but that does not throw an exception (to the user) from a custom workflow activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because workflow processes run asynchronously, you cannot really "present" an error to a user immediately as it occurs. The exception details are logged though whenever an exception is thrown; if you look under Settings -> System Jobs (or the Processes tab on the entity record the workflow was kicked off from) a workflow job record with a status of **Failed** will be present. This record will show you where in the workflow the exception occurred along with the details of the exception.

One way I can think of off the top of my head to notify the user of an exception would be to catch the errors and kick off an email (if it's really necessary).

I have not played with Dialogs yet so I'm not sure how they handle exceptions in custom assemblies, but that might be a route to check.

Comment: Note that even though the exception is not presented to the user as a dialog, if you throw InvalidPluginExecutionException, then the message is displayed to the user as described by GotDibbs as seen [here](http://postimage.org/image/1re90d5l0/). Also, [Jonathan Nachman](http://bit.ly/j4pSvl) shows how to add tracing comments that are visible in the details pane of the system job.